# How can 'The Humble Dialog Box' be implement in Python 3 using the unittest framework?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mvp

[This](http://duganchen.ca/a-humble-dialog-implementation-in-pyqt/) link shows an example using the nose test suite, however I am interested in understanding how this would look with the standard unittest test suite.

Further, in the link provided, what is the purpose of the @properties that are used, i.e. @selectionList.Setter

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the [official documentation about Unit tests in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is  pretty straightforward and the link you posted does not show anything that could not be done with another unit testing framework.

If you follow the tutorial, you can find your own way to write unit tests with pyunit.

In regards to the question about properties, there is a whole bunch of pages you might find useful:

- [Python @property](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)
- [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)
- [Python @property decorator (official doc.)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)